# how to install DeepSpeech (2023)

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech

I understand DeepSpeech project is not being maintained now hence it cannot be installed using pip. I get the following error when trying to install using `python3 setup.py install` after cloning the source code.

> Searching for tensorflow==1.15.4
> Reading https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/
> No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow==1.15.4
> error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow==1.15.4')

I don't want to downgrade my python in local device as there are other projects running the latest python version. I tried creating a virtual env and downgrading python but it didn't work (probably i misfollowed the steps). Im tryin to run it in google colab now.

Is there any way to install DeepSpeech in 2023?

Comment: The package is still on PyPi. Is there a reason not to install from there?

Comment: it cannot be installed using PyPi since they discontinued maintaining it. `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deepspeech`.